# Why is a test taking forever to execute

Tags: java, testing

When building a maven project I have forked, it runs several test classes located in src/test, one test class is especially troublesome: TestWriteAndRead

When trying to run this class, the test never completes.

```java
package regalowl.simpledatalib.sql;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

import regalowl.simpledatalib.SimpleDataLib;
import regalowl.simpledatalib.TestLogger;
import regalowl.simpledatalib.sql.Field;
import regalowl.simpledatalib.sql.FieldType;
import regalowl.simpledatalib.sql.SQLManager;
import regalowl.simpledatalib.sql.Table;

public class TestWriteAndRead {
    @Test
    public void testCreateShutdownAndLoad() {
        SimpleDataLib sdl = new SimpleDataLib("test");
        sdl.initialize();
        sdl.setDebug(true);
        new TestLogger(sdl);
        SQLManager sm = sdl.getSQLManager();
        sm.setWriteTaskInterval(1L);
        sm.createDatabase();

        SQLWrite sw = sm.getSQLWrite();
        Table t = sm.addTable("hyperconomy_object_data");
        Field f = t.addField("ID", FieldType.INTEGER);f.setPrimaryKey();f.setAutoIncrement();
        f = t.addField("DATA", FieldType.TEXT);
        sm.saveTables();
        sw.writeSync(true);
        String statement = "DELETE FROM hyperconomy_object_data";
        sw.addToQueue(statement);
        sw.writeSyncQueue();
        sw.writeSync(false);


        statement = "INSERT INTO hyperconomy_object_data (ID, DATA) VALUES ('" + 1 + "', ?)";
        WriteStatement ws = new WriteStatement(statement, sdl);
        ws.addParameter("test");
        sw.addToQueue(ws);


        sm.shutDown();


        sdl.initialize();
        sdl.setDebug(true);
        new TestLogger(sdl);
        sm = sdl.getSQLManager();
        sm.createDatabase();
        SQLRead sr = sm.getSQLRead();
        QueryResult qr  = sr.select("SELECT * FROM hyperconomy_object_data WHERE ID = '1'");
        qr.next();
        assertTrue(qr.getString("DATA").equals("test"));
    }
}
```

No error messages are returned. The test starts, but never ends

Comment: Did you step through with a debugger? Where does it get to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked out the project you are using from https://github.com/RegalOwl/SimpleDataLib
and it seems that it has a concurrency boohoo in the getActiveStatements method of the private class WriteTask inside SQLWrite class.

The test is flaky and it gets stuck on the shutdown call at line 43. Once it passed in debug and I saw the `synchronized` used without a dedicated lock object I immediately suspected concurrency issues. Now it is really time consuming to investigate these types of problems which I don't have, but I can offer you a quick and mindless change to the original code that seems to solve the problem:

```
private class WriteTask extends TimerTask {
    ReentrantLock activeStatementsLock = new ReentrantLock();

    //...keep the rest the same

    public ArrayList<WriteStatement> getActiveStatements() {
        synchronized (activeStatementsLock) {
            return writeData;
        }
    }
}
```

When you use `synchronized` on method you are essentially doing the same that my code does, but instead of using the dedicated `activeStatementsLock` object you are using the instance object on which this method is executed (equivalent to using `synchronized (this)`). But when you have several such methods it is easy to get in all sorts of trouble like deadlocks and whatnot and so you can group these synchronized blocks by having several dedicated lock objects.

In this case the active statements seem to be unrelated to other two and splitting them is potentially safe, but I cannot give you guarantees.

Please note that I don't know the root cause of the issue and so I'm not sure how this code fixes the problem (or rather I don't have time to get to the bottom of this) and for a better solution you should submit this as a bug to the github issues at https://github.com/RegalOwl/SimpleDataLib/issues, where a dedicated contributor will be happy to fix issues in his own project.

Comment: This really solved the problem. Also, up to this point, deadlocks was for me an unknown phenomenon. Thanks alot